# ReactJS conditional rendering "Nothing was returned from render"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to render a simple page in react when the session storage has an valid authentication token in it.
For that purpose I used the following code:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';


function conditionaltest() {  

  switch (sessionStorage.getItem('token')) {
    case null:
      window.location.replace("/login");
      return(<h1>Auth failed</h1>)
    default:
      const verifyjson = {
        "verify": {
          "token": sessionStorage.getItem('token')
        }
      }
      axios.post('/api/verifylogin', verifyjson)
          .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data.verification)
            return (<h1>Test valid login</h1>)
          })
          .catch((reason) => {
            console.log("Token invalid, please login again")
            sessionStorage.removeItem('token')
            window.location.replace("/login");
            return(<h1>Auth failed</h1>)
          })
  }
}

export default conditionaltest;
```

The problem with that is the following: "Nothing was returned from render." which to me says that there was a state where nothing was returned. But as far as I see every statement has a correct return value. So I guess something fundamental is wrong here. What's the issue?

Comment: You are returning content from then and catch blocks. By the time they get called, you function finishes execution. So use promise to return response.

Comment: The problem React is complaining about is that your function doesn't return anything in the `default` case. (You have `return`s in `then`/`catch` callbacks, but they have no effect on the containing functions.) The more basic problem is that you can't delay a component rendering like that, you **must** return the React elements synchronously. The usual solution when you're doing something asynchronous like this is to either A) do it in the parent component and render the child when you have the necessary data, or B) render a "loading" state in the child, then re-render once you have the data.